# Mapping DB column value to C# enum attribute value

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a simple class, of which one of the properties is an enum. For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender 
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "M")]
    Male, // database uses 'M' instead of 'Male'

    [EnumMember(Value = "F")]
    Female // database uses 'F' instead of 'Female'
}
```

My data is stored with slightly different values for Gender - `M` instead of `Male`, and `F` instead of `Female`. For example:

[image]

How can I map the DB value of `M` to the enum value of `Gender.Male`, and likewise, `F` to `Gender.Female`?

Comment: Dapper sees enums as their base types.

Answer (score 2):

There is an opened issue in Dapper for this use case: [#259](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/259). Looks like aliases for enums are not possible until it's fixed.